# Struts2 configuration and performance

Tags: frameworks, jakarta-ee, struts2

I use Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate for web site development. And I am wondering about 1 thing, I never used annotations in my web applications, but hey, what is the best way to code a web application? Annotations (I never understood how they works) or Config-files? and why? More complex applications will work faster on this?, or is something about principles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't definitive it is just what I do with similar tools.

Looking at the Struts2 xml configuration vs conventions (struts2-conventions-plugin) and annotations. The benefit of the later is that there is a lot less work. When the conventions don't do what we want we have a choice, use struts.xml which will override the conventions or use annotations which will also override the conventions.  If you go with annotations on your action class then you can clearly see what is going on from one location.  With struts.xml you often need to look at both the configuration file and the action to understand the whole picture.

Although I advocate annotations, the xml configuration is still good for somethings.  It is a good place to set global parameters. It is still needed for defining custom interceptors/interceptor-stacks and if you need actions defined from wildcards it makes sense to have them there too.  All these examples reinforce the point that it is more general configuration that belongs in struts.xml because they are bigger than any action.

For hibernate it is similar.  Your entity classes and meta information are all in one place which makes it easier to understand.  There was a case I had where xml was more useful in a testing situation, I needed to use the same entity classes but needed to make extensive changes to the metadata.  So in that case I could simply load a different set of xml files.

With spring I use annotations for injection but wire the beans in application.xml.

Comment: Thanks, now I know what's the deal :)

Answer (score 3):

Other stackoverflow posts that may be of interest:

- [Xml configuration versus Annotation based configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182393/xml-configuration-versus-annotation-based-configuration)
- [Is there a good reason to configure hibernate with XML rather than via annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452669/is-there-a-good-reason-to-configure-hibernate-with-xml-rather-than-via-annotation)